# angualr.js expressions don't get evaluated

Tags: angularjs, expression

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    {{2+2}}
```

Why the {{2+2}} expression does not get evaluated to 4 ?
Am i missing a dependency ?

Comment: http://learn-angular.org/, you need to put atleast `ng-app` for bootstrapping to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [`ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive to your body:

```
<body ng-app>
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/pkm5wo0c/).